# Как лучше хранить сообщения чата?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, чат

Варианты, которые я вижу:

1. Есть массив сообщений текущего чата. Есть observable, который создается для уведомления подписчиков на новые сообщения. И каждое новое сообщение кидается в массив.
2. Есть observable, который хранит в себе массивом сразу все сообщения открытого чата (или всех открытых в сессии, тут тоже не знаю, как лучше). При получении нового сообщения, оно добавляется в массив.
3. Есть observable, который хранит только последнее сообщение и уведомляет о нем подписчиков. То есть если добавляется сообщение то все подписчики тригерят функции и добавляют в html новые сообщения, а всего списка не хранят. Ну или хранят до уничтожения компонента.

Если имеет значение, то сообщения чата хранятся в бд и получаются через сокеты.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удобнее, оптимизированее и грамотнее реализовать эту функцию? По возможности объясните, почему именно так

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю такой вариант.

Observable не хранит состояние, только получает событие и шлет подписчикам.

История чата существует как отдельный объект на сервере, загружается и кэшируется клиентом.

Хранение данных на клиенте зависит от фреймворка, можно использовать редьюсеры, либо SessionStorage для Vanilla JS.

При отправке сообщения, клиент выкидывает событие, и, поскольку он подписан на Observable, при получении этого сообщения, выставляет ему флаг как отправленному.

Главное преимущество такой схемы - высокая отказоустойчивость. При падении сервиса, можно его переподнять, или добавить новые инстансы в цепочку в случае высокой нагрузки.

Главный минус - история хранится на клиенте, и со временем, может сильно нагружать браузер. Чтобы этого не произошло, можно использовать пагинацию истории и подгружать по мере прокрутки.